# doctrine2 persist and flush

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

in my case

symfony2

try to flush my rows on loop but i got error.

what did i miss ?

```
foreach ($request->request as $key => $val) {
  $form_result->setTitle($request->request->get('form-title-title-12431243'));
  $form_result->setFieldId($request->request->get('form-title-id-12431243'));
  $form_result->setKey($key);
  $form_result->setIp($request->getClientIp());
  $form_result->setType($request->request->get('form-title-type-12431243'));
  $form_result->setValue($val);

  $em->persist($form_result);
  $em->flush();
}
```

error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, type, field_id, ip) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'form-title-title-12431243', 't' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column named `key` is [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). It's good practice to avoid using reserved keywords, but in cases you must use it use reserved words quoting to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`key` is [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. Use [reserved words quoting](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words) to fix the issue.